# Karma can't recognize angular directives

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

Our project structure follows this: [Angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter).

Our project successfully compiles, build and can be seen in the browser. No problems here.

But when we try to run the test cases using `karma and jasmine` we are getting this error.

```
FAILED TESTS:
 XXXXXXComponent
   :heavy_multiplication_x: Should Match Current Tab as 1
     Chrome 55.0.2883 (Mac OS X 10.10.5)
   Error: Template parse errors:
   Can't bind to 'formgroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("                <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                                           <form novalidate [ERROR ->][formgroup]="step1Form" class="height-full" >
                                               <div class="row" id="tabHeader1">
             "): XXXXXXComponent@38:27
   Can't bind to 'dividerColor' since it isn't a known property of 'md-input'.
   1. If 'md-input' is an Angular component and it has 'dividerColor' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
   2. If 'md-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    ("ass = "col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                                                           <div class="form-group">
                                                               <md-input [ERROR ->]dividerColor="{{getDividerColor(lexiconTitle)}}" placeholder="Lexicon Title" formControlName="lexicon"): XXXXXXComponent@52:25
   Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'md-input'.
   1. If 'md-input' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
   2. If 'md-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    ("olor="{{getDividerColor(lexiconTitle)}}" placeholder="Lexicon Title" formControlName="lexiconTitle" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="blogModel.lexiconTitle" name="lexiconTitle" class="md-form-control" required>
                                           "):
```

We have imported all these modules in the app.module.ts as required by new angular convention.

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    ...
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ... ],
  providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
    ENV_PROVIDERS,
    APP_PROVIDERS
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

We have all the latest versions of packages installed.

```
"karma": "^1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "2.0.1",
"webpack": "2.2.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.2.0",
"webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"webpack-md5-hash": "~0.0.5",
"webpack-merge": "~2.4.0"
```

TestBed Setup:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [ XXXXComponent ], // declare the test component
});
```

Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: That's odd -- both of the errors appear to be errors you would expect to be found at runtime.  You mentioned it compiles and runs -- are the views in question being rendered during your manual testing?  The html bindings are invalid in the errors.

Comment: How are you obtaining the XXXXComponent instance in the test (or are you yet)?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you need dividerColor directive inside your md-input-container tags instead of md-input.